# Intersystem cache truncate numeric value

Tags: hibernate, intersystems-cache

I faced with strange behavior of Intersystem Cache.

When I try to get data from Cache on our test server using java hibernate I always get truncated version of number. E. g. 0,5 converted to 0; 1,6 to 2 etc.

Strange but the DB from my local machine with same DB schema return digit as expected 0,5 is 0,5; 1,6 is 1,6 ans so on.

May be Cache have setting that truncate number?

Update try to check genereated SQL by hibernate

```
select kpdrawing0_.ID_KPDRAW as ID1_17_,
        kpdrawing0_.VERSION as VERSION17_,
        kpdrawing0_.DRAWING_DATE as DRAWING3_17_,
        kpdrawing0_.DrawingNumber as DrawingN4_17_,
        kpdrawing0_.TICKETPRICE as TICKETPR5_17_,
        kpdrawing0_.REALIZATION_STATE as REALIZAT6_17_ 
    from
        SaleService.tblKPDraw kpdrawing0_ 
    where
        kpdrawing0_.REALIZATION_STATE=? 
    order by
        kpdrawing0_.ID_KPDRAW asc
```

If I try to invoke this sql in any other SQL editor it return me truncated numbers (TICKETPRICE field).

If I change as TICKETPR5_17_ to any other alliase then SQL editor return to me numbers that are not truncated

Comment: What if you write SQL query in Caché directly? Via JDBC, without Hibernate. Will the value still be truncated?

Comment: No, simple jdbc without Hibernate does not truncate numbers.

Comment: Can you check what SQL query Hibernate produces?

Comment: If the same query returns not truncated values when being run via JDBC, then I think the problem in Hibernate settings.